# Laravel 5.2 Auth register users only by logged user or by admin only

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have an issue with laravel route. I want that auth register route can be access by only admin or logged users. To achieve this i have removed `Route::auth();` from routes.php and create my own route entry in auth middleware.

**Effort**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

    // Authentication Routes...
    $this->get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
    $this->post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
    $this->get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');

    // Password Reset Routes...
    $this->get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
    $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
    $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::post('/ajax/getStates', 'ConfigurationController@getStates');
    Route::post('/ajax/getCities', 'ConfigurationController@getCities');


});


Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth']], function () {

    // Registration Routes...
    $this->get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
    $this->post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');

});
```

Above code working fine. when i tried to access register url it simply redirect me to the login page. Now actual problem start after login.

After login, i tried to access register page, but it does not show up, instead it redirect me to the home like `http://localhost/`.

Please suggest me the solution.

Comment: Its because you have set your `register route` within your `auth` middleware instead you need to get it within your `web` middleware only so you can access it without logging

Comment: I want it should be access by logged user, not anonymous user. that is why i put this in auth middleware.

Comment: Then why're you having it within your `AuthController`

Comment: This is the requirement that only administrator can register new user or any appointed authorized user can. I am using laravel existing auth register. There is no point how should auth will be used, thing is that you should able to use it there own way.

Answer (score 2):

Check your AuthController's constructor. It has the guest middleware assigned to all methods except `logout`.

Comment: I know, i have passed getRegister and postregister into that too. But thats not work for me, so i have removed that from constructor and now registration form working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got a simple solution. I am not expert, but I am going by this way and It's working as you want.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
Route::auth();

Route::get('/edit', function () {
    if (Auth::user()) {
        return view('auth.user_edit'); //Page which you want to show for loged user.
    } else {
        return "MM"; //You can redirect from here, if user is not logged in
    }
});
});
```